# How to handle the NetworkImage error if the URL not exists or the response is an error?

Tags: flutter, dart

How to handle the NetworkImage error if the URL not exists or the response is an error?

I specify that i'm using NetworkImage, not Image.network, so please answer only if you have a solution for NetworkImage.
Thank you!

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/errorBuilder.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Image widget

```
Image(
      image: NetworkImage('Some URL'),
      errorBuilder:(context, error, stackTrace) {
           return SomeWidget();
     })
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
return Image(
      errorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) {
        return Container(
          height: 20,
          width: 20,
          color: Colors.red,
        );
      },
      image: const NetworkImage(
        'https://i.guim.co.uk/img/media/fe1e34da640c5c56ed16f76ce6f994fa9343d09d/0_174_3408_2046/master/3408.jpg?width=1200&height=900&quality=85&auto=format&fit=crop&s=0d3f33fb4b7713a00454c83d',
      ),
    );
```